# Unit tests with MEF2 ExportFactories

Tags: c#, mef

We have just recently switched to using .Net4.5 and I am doing some refactoring to take advantage of the new ExportFactories.

My question is how do I mock these for unit testing as I inject them into my constructor, but I'm not 100% sure on the best approach to these from a unit testing standpoint.

Comment: Can you provide some code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of [ExportFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382798%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes a function that returns a tuple containing the export and another function that release the export. So you can do something like that:

```
static Tuple<ISomething, Action> CreateMock()
{        
    return new Tuple<ISomething, Action>(new MockSomething(), 
                                         () => Console.WriteLine("Releasing..."));
}
```

and inject it to your other class' constructor with something like:

```
var obj = new OtherClass(new ExportFactory<ISomething>(CreateMock));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i ended up doing.